# How can I use information from IF statements?

Tags: c#

I was wondering if I can use the information from a IF statement to do another task. :D
I tried finding the answer on other posts on Stackoverflow but couldn't find a topic about it.

```
        int randomNumber;
        int scoreTeamOne = 0; // Default number
        Random randm = new Random();
        randomNumber = randm.Next(1, 101);
        

        Console.WriteLine("The random number is " + randomNumber);
        //Checking if the number is right with the if statement

        if(randomNumber > 0 && randomNumber < 31) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(scoreTeamOne + 0);
            // How can I get this to do + 0 to scoreTeamOne?
        }

        else if(randomNumber > 31 && randomNumber < 61) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(scoreTeamOne + 1);
            // How can I get this to do + 1 to scoreTeamOne?
        }

        else if(randomNumber > 61) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(scoreTeamOne + 2);
            // How can I get this to do + 2 to scoreTeamOne?
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The points is/are: " + scoreTeamOne);
```

`

Comment: The body of an `if` or `else if` can contain more than one statement when enclosed in `{` and `}`. So what is stopping you from adding a number to your variable?

Comment: Your conditions will miss 31 and 61

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently not actually changing the variables, just printing the result of the arithmetic expression. For example, `Console.WriteLine(scoreTeamOne + 2);` prints the result of `scoreTeamOne + 2` but does not affect the result of `scoreTeamOne` at all.

Instead, you should do something like:

```
else if(randomNumber > 61) 
{
    scoreTeamOne += 2;
    Console.WriteLine(scoreTeamOne);
}
```

Also, as a side note, there really isn't any point to `scoreTeamOne + 0` because it'll always be the same result as `scoreTeamOne`.